# Knots selection testing for Natural Cubic Splines model in R

Tags: r, spline

I have a dataset of Japan's Mortality rate and want to fit a natural cubic spline to this mortality data. The choice of knots are subjectively chosen at 10, 20, 30,...,90. I want to know whether or not it was a good choice to place those knots at those positions or not. Here the number of possible combinations of knot placements is 2^9 = 512, thus we need to test 512 models. What process/functions in R could be used to test that? (For demonstration, please use the 2017 dataset as the calibration data and 2018 dataset as the validation data).

Mortality data for Japan can be obtained from the Human Mortality Database (2014). To download the mortality data for Japan type the following commands, noting that "username" and "password" needs to be replaced by your logging information from the Human Mortality Database:

```
library(demography)
Japan.data <- hmd.mx(country = "JPN", username = "username", password = "password")
```